# Click a tag to opening new tab using Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I just want the relevent `<td>` class to click on a tag and I must do this by opening it on a new tab. Here is my code:

```
x1=driver.find_element_by_class_name('no').send_keys(Keys.COMMAND + 't')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please try following :

```
x1=driver.find_element_by_class_name('no') 


ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.COMMAND).click(x1).key_up(Keys.COMMAND).perform() 

browser.switch_to.window(browser.window_handles[1])
```

Comment: NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".no"}
  (Session info: chrome=78.0.3904.108)

Comment: Are you sure you are using true locator? Because exception says it is css selector. @FeyzullahErtan

Answer (score 1):

One problem here is there are multiple `td` elements with `class='no'` so it is hard to tell which one you need to click. Because 2nd element in your list is highlighted, we can make the assumption you are trying to click the 2nd `a` link.

It sounds like you are trying to get the `a` element so that you can click on the link & clicking this will open a new tab. You'll need to first locate the `a` to click, then switch focus to the newly opened tab:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait


# get number of currently open windows
windows_before = len(driver.window_handles)

# click link -- [2] specifies which one to click, change this to click different one
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[@class='no'][2]/a").click()

# wait up to 10s for new tab to open, then switch focus to new tab
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver: len(windows_before) != len(driver.window_handles))

# switch to new window
driver.switch_to_window(len(driver.window_handles)-1)
```

The above code first stores the number of currently opened tabs using `driver.window_handles`. Then, once we click the **2nd** `a` element to open `event328706602.html` link, we invoke `WebDriverWait` on number of open windows. Note that you will need to update `[2]` in the XPath depending on which `a` element you need to click.

In `WebDriverWait`, we wait for the number of windows to be *greater* than the value we previous stored, so we know the new window has been opened. Then, we switch to the new window handle by checking `len(driver.window_handles)` and switch to the last `window_handle` index the list.